# SSRS print button issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The ssrs report print button is not working in any browsers i.e. on click of it their is no effect.

Also the find/next buttons are not visible on mozilla firefox and are visible on other browsers

Is it the version problem of report viewer of some other issue? please guide me through it asap

Comment: The SSRS report manager/server UI print button uses an ActiveX control to print.  Is it possible that this is not allowed on your company's computers? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: As per the link sent by you, I do not get any prompt to install the activex control. The print button has not effect on click